# Como fazer os ands do where dinamicamente com linq e Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Como posso fazer os `ands` dinamicamente no `where` utilizando o Linq e entityFramework?

Desde de já agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

```
return _dbContext.TbParceiro                
//Preciso fazer algo do tipo mas isso não funciona, não sei como posso fazer aqui.
.Where(p =>                   

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId))
    {
         p.ParceiroId = mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId;
    }
)
.OrderBy(p => p.ParceiroId)
.Skip(mdlParceiroFiltro.Pula)
.Take(mdlParceiroFiltro.Pega)
.ToList();
```

Abaixo tem um exemplo que funciona ultilizando comando em string, preciso fazer a mesma coisa só que com linq.

```
        sql.Append("SELECT u.Id, u.Nome, u.Usuario ");
        sql.Append("FROM usuario u ");
        sql.Append("WHERE 1 = 1 ");

        if (model != null) 
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Nome))
            {
                sql.Append("AND u.Nome like @Nome ");
                lstParametros.Add(new MySqlParameter() {
                    ParameterName = "@Nome",
                    MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String,
                    Value = "%" + model.Nome + "%"
                });
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Usuario))
            {
                sql.Append("AND u.Usuario like @Usuario ");
                lstParametros.Add(new MySqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Usuario",
                    MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String,
                    Value = "%" + 
                    model.Usuario + "%"
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você quer é adicionar o `Where` somente se o `mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId` não for `null` ou empty.

```
IQueryable<ParceiroModel> entidades = _dbContext.TbParceiro;

// Verifica o FiltroId é válido
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId))
{
    // Se for válido, você insere o Where
    entidades = entidades.Where(p => p.ParceiroId == mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId);
}

return entidades
    .OrderBy(p => p.ParceiroId)
    .Skip(mdlParceiroFiltro.Pula)
    .Take(mdlParceiroFiltro.Pega)
    .ToList();
```

Você pode adicionar quantos `Where` quiser com o LINQ. Ele vai automaticamente transformar em `and` por baixo dos panos.

Comment: Legal, mas nessa linha "var entidades = _dbContext.TbParceiro;" ele não vai fazer um full select no banco?

Comment: Não, o `dbContext` só executa o select quando você chama um método finalizador, tipo o `ToList` ou `ToArray`, por exemplo. Enquanto você só adicionar filtros, ele vai montando o select sem executar.

Comment: Perfeito. Valeu

Comment: Ele reclamou de uma conversão ai invés de eu usar o var coloquei IQueryable<ParceiroModel> entidades = _dbContext.TbParceiro;

Comment: Entendi, pensei que o `var` fosse pegar automaticamente o tipo `IQueryable`.

Comment: Alterei a resposta pra refletir o que você comentou.

Answer (score 2):

tente com operador ternário:

Sintaxe:  `((bool) ? (se true) : (se falso))`

```
[...].Where(p => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Nome) ? p.Nome.Contains(model.Nome) : p.Usuario.Contains(model.Usuario))).[...]
```

Outro exemplo:

```
[...].Where(p => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId) ? p.ParceiroId = mdlParceiroFiltro.FiltroId : true)).[...]
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua ajuda +1